# Calibrate Touch screen permanently

Tags: touchscreen

I have a usb touchscreen and a calibration app, but whenever the usb gets bumped it uncalibrates. Is there a way to permanently calibrate it?

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what calibration app you are using, but I found using `xinput_calibrator` the app spits out a code snippet for you to cut and paste into a persistence file. The catch is, the correct location of that file (if you are using Ubuntu) is NOT the same as the one it prescribes. The correct location on Ubuntu is in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

After creating the `99-calibration.conf` file in the correct location, logging out and logging in again should not affect the calibration.

You can download and install `xinput_calibrator` via apt-get from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
    sudo apt-get install xinput-calibrator
```

Comment: I have this application and it works great. I actually figured this out a few weeks ago. The only problem is that after inserting the new line of code, unity crashed and so I have to run off gnome classic now. Runs faster though.

Comment: @Justin I posted the entire code snippet (not just one line) in a separate file. No problems with Unity. But, yes, it probably runs faster not using 3-d graphics on the desktop...

Comment: For me I needed a dash (not an understore) like this: sudo apt-get install xinput-calibrator

Comment: Thx @Peter, typo corrected! The command is `xinput_calibrator`, but as you point out the package name uses a hyphen, i.e. `xinput-calibrator`.

Comment: Note this gets confusing on other distros... Arch linux currently has this in the user repository as `xinput_calibrator`.